# Do nothing if no file is selected php

Tags: php

This works great. Thing is, if the user does not choose a file, there is an error. How can I make this not check anything if no file is selected and only check for errors if a file is selected.

This function is inside a `<form>` and runs when the form is submitted.

```
if (empty($errors) === true){
    if (isset($_FILES['cover']) === true){
        $allowed = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png');
        $file_name = $_FILES['cover']['name'];
        $file_size = getimagesize($_FILES['cover']['name']);
        $file_extn = strtolower(end(explode('.', $file_name)));
        $file_temp = $_FILES['cover']['tmp_name'];
        if(in_array($file_extn, $allowed) === true){            
            $file_path = 'images/cover/' . substr(md5(time()), 0, 10) . '.' . $file_extn;
            move_uploaded_file($file_temp, $file_path);
        }else{
                $errors[] = 'Incorrect file type. Only allowed: ' . implode(', ', $allowed) . '';                                       
            }
    }
```

Comment: Are you requiring a file submission every time? Or is it optional?

Comment: Unrelated: `isset()` always returns a bool. You don't have to check for `=== true` or even `== true`. This will do it: `if (isset($_FILES['cover'])) { ...`

Comment: @les it is optional, i tried empty($_FILES['cover']), but that is just saying, if it is empty, show errors, it doesn't say if empty just ignore it. wouldn't die() simply kill the page?

Comment: @bamba check my answer below. If this doesn't work let me know - I have a working script that I can pull up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about testing if it or the rest of the data is set to nothing?

```
if (!empty($_FILES['cover'])) {
    if ($_FILES['cover']['name'] != "") {
        // execute your code here

    } else if ($_FILES['cover']['name'] == "") {
        // do nothing
        // or header them to the appropriate page
        header("location: http://yourpage.com");
        exit();
    }
}
```

I added this to see if we are on the same page.

```
if (!empty($_FILES['cover'])){
    if ( $_FILES['cover']['name'] != "") {
        $file_name = $_FILES['cover']['name'];    
        // etc
        // then the rest of your code

    } else {
        // do nothing

    }
} else {
    // do nothing or header to appropriate location and exit
    header("location: http://yourpage.com");
    exit();
}
```

Okay Try this:

```
if(!empty($_FILES['cover'])) {
    if($_FILES['cover']['tmp_name'] != "") {
        $fileName     = $_FILES["cover"]["name"];
        $fileTmpLoc   = $_FILES["cover"]["tmp_name"];
        $fileType     = $_FILES["cover"]["type"];
        $fileSize     = $_FILES["cover"]["size"];
        $fileErrorMsg = $_FILES["cover"]["error"];
        $boomBoom     = explode(".", $fileName);
        $fileExt      = end($boomBoom);

        // this next if is okay because if a new file is not selected 
        // the script wouldn't make it this far anyway
        // so this will not require a new selection
        // just a check that should pass every time

        if (!$fileTmpLoc){
            echo "ERROR: Please browse for a file before uploading";
            exit();
        }
        else if($fileSize > 20480000){
            echo "ERROR: Your file was larger than 20 Megabytes";
            unlink($fileTmpLoc);
            exit();
        }
        else if (!preg_match("/.(gif|jpg|png|jpeg)$/i", $fileName)){
            echo "ERROR: Your image was not .gif, .jpg, .jpeg, or .png.";
            unlink($fileTmpLoc);
            exit();
        }
        else if ($fileErrorMsg == 1){
            echo "ERROR: An error occurred.";
            exit();
        }

        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['cover']['tmp_name'], "pathTo/$fileName");
        header("location: http://www.yoursite.com");
        exit();
    }
}
```

Comment: how do you tell it "do nothing"?

Comment: @bamba By literally not writing anything down. Then you `exit();`. You don't really have to put in the else if condition. A simple else would do. `else { exit(); }`

Comment: edit: it does work acutally but it doesn't submit anything now as it exit() right.. is there another way?

Comment: solved it! simply removed the else and it worked! thanks for all the help

Comment: @bamba yes you wouldn't want to exit unless you intended to redirect or refresh the page etc.

Comment: now the problem is if i try to edit the post and i dont select a file, it will go through and not display the previous file before the edit.. does that make sense? how can i tell it, if there is already a file stored and no new file is selected, display the old one, otherwise switch to new one (if no errors obviously)

Comment: If a new a selected, the browser will switch it for you. How are you storing your data?

Comment: i take the file path and input it into the database then pull the path out to display the image. yes it will replace it, but what if a new one isn't selected? right now it replaces it with the placeholder rather than keeping the old image before the edit was made

Comment: can anyone help me out with this? i have been trying to solve this for three days now!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this would work for you...

```
if (!empty($_FILES['cover'])){
if (empty($errors) === true){
    if (isset($_FILES['cover'])){
        $allowed = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png');
        $file_name = $_FILES['cover']['name'];
        $file_size = getimagesize($_FILES['cover']['name']);
        $file_extn = strtolower(end(explode('.', $file_name)));
        $file_temp = $_FILES['cover']['tmp_name'];
        if(in_array($file_extn, $allowed) === true){            
            $file_path = 'images/cover/' . substr(md5(time()), 0, 10) . '.' . $file_extn;
            move_uploaded_file($file_temp, $file_path);
        }else{
                $errors[] = 'Incorrect file type. Only allowed: ' . implode(', ', $allowed) . '';                                       
            }
    } 

}
```

Comment: how can i get it to keep the same image (when editing the post) if nothing new is selected?

Comment: Duplicate the data into a hidden field then do a comparison against the two when the form is posted to find out if a change has occurred.

Comment: can you tell me how to do that? i mean, how do i compare the old uploaded file to a new one (or empty)?

Comment: can you please help me out?